# Return value if length equal character count in a large range in Excel

Tags: excel

So I am trying to return the value if the cell has a character count of 40.
=IF(LEN(Sheet1!B1)=40,Sheet1!B1)

However, I want find that value in a large range B1:Z100.
I tried entering the range in the Len() formula, example (len(B1:Z100)) but it returned a SPILL.
How can I do this without having to write the formula below:
=IF(LEN(Sheet1!B1)=40,Sheet1!B1,LEN(Sheet1!C1)=40,C1,etc...)

Appreciate the help!

Comment: You got a SPILL error because it was trying to drop a dynamic array for each cell in the range, and you have existing values in the way.  You need to have a 25x100 (ish) area clear for the formula to return.  Also, if you don't specify the [value_if_false] parameter it will default to FALSE.

Comment: So how should the formula be written?